# High frequency ultrasound effects on viruses and bacteria

Tags: ultrasound, waves

Might anyone have any clue on how high frequency ultrasound have effect on killing viruses and bacteria on surfaces (GHz/MHz)? There have been a few articles online that say ultrasound has effect on viruses and bacteria with literally shaking the virus until inactivation.

How could ultrasound effect for instance COVID 19 or virus similiar DNA/RNA/retroviruses where destroying the outer layer or the membrane layer of the virus/bacteria etc with GHz/MHz? How is virus/bacteria protein layer strength and durability determined anyway? What units are used to determine virus/bacteria membrane layer strength?

Would it be possible to introduce for example two separate transducers, for the waves to intersect on different areas, would then allow tearing the virus apart or can changing the beam type rapidly(continuous beam, pulsed beam etc) with rotation be an effective way to twist the outer membrane of a virus well enough for it to be destroyed successfully in a short period of time?

Source:

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2002/12/021216071144.htm - December 16, 2002

http://adamasuniversity.ac.in/virus-and-vibrations/ - March 30, 2020

https://www.livescience.com/7472-kill-viruses-shake-death.html February 05, 2008

Comment: How do you get the ultrasound to differentiate between your good cells and the virus?

Comment: Hello, that is not important, important is to allow removing viruses from surfaces such as metal, plastic, paper etc(from close range). Good cells would not participate in the removal of viruses in this case

Comment: It is my understand that the covid-19 has a lipid membrane. There is possibility that ultrasonic could break the lipid protective layer. When this happens the COVID-19 becomes inactive. It is my understanding that hand washing with soap accomplishes the same objective. Additionally that harder problem is acquire sufficient evidence the ultrasonics can be effective.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is addressed around COVID-19, which is trending these days this response is focused on COVID-19 and using electronics to destroy the virus. The response is focused around destroying any live COVID-19 on surfaces as mentioned in comment.

Soap works best to destroy the virus. Here is good explanation.

[image: COVID-19 Soap Works best]

[How soap kills the coronavirus?](https://youtu.be/-LKVUarhtvE)

In practice it is impossible to wash everything with soap and water every day. For example washing the Metropolitan Transportation Authority in New York (AKA subway), thus high frequency ultrasonic joins the conversation.

As mentioned briefly mentioned in question body, and greater detail in the mentioned references COVID-19 has a lipid layer or [phospholipid bilayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid_bilayer) that protects the RNA strain.

This phospholipid bilayer consists on hydrophilic head and a hydrophobic tail as show in the image below

[image]

To destroy the virus this phospholipid bilayer has to be destroyed. As describe about soap effectively destroys the phospholipid bilayer.

Likewise ultrasonics can do the same. The key is to find the resonance frequency the shatters the phospholipid bilayer.

A place to start experimenting is to use piezoceramic transducer combine with Analog Front End (AFE) such as [TDC1000](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tdc1000.pdf?ts=1590973639051) from Texas Instruments combined with a micro controller with one transducer at the specific resonance frequency for COVID-19.

[image]

As mentioned above validating the result will be very challenging.

**Disclaimer:** I am by no means an expert on Virus, just happened to be in associating which smart people who are studying this topic thus happen to some peripheral knowledge.